# Converting CSV string array to int array gives 'input string was not in the correct format'

Tags: csv

Ive tried a bunch of Array.Convertall formats and all of them give me this error.  Its just a list of numbers in CRLF CSV format?

999339,
219199,
282833,
122322,

The string array is being read correctly as I can view that fine. I just cant convert it.

```
string[] TempString = File.ReadAllLines(@"try.csv");
int[] TempArray;
TempArray = Array.ConvertAll(TempString, p => Convert.ToInt32(p));
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the commas got this working.